# How to find capital gain from 1099 B form automatically

Tags: income-tax, investing, capital-gain

Are there any program that can import 1099 B pdf file and then calculate capital gain for me automatically ?
Turbotax sorta able to do this.
However, Turbotax won't let me upload the form, but they can find capital gain for me by importaing my 1099 B form if I log in to my broker account, but some of my broker cant connect to Turbotax.
Thanks

Comment: Here's a [possible solution](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/122006/question-about-calculating-wash-sales-across-multiple-orders/122008#122008).   I have used Tradelog and it downloads from the major brokers, accurately calculates cap gains, wash sales, etc. and the results can be exported.

Comment: You might consider taxing your documents to a local tax preparer who will do this for you for a fee.

Comment: You can always choose to enter your form manually in TurboTax rather than import it from your broker (even if import from your broker is supported).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "calculate capital gain". Literally, the "capital gain" is the amount you got when you sold it minus the amount you paid for it, and both proceeds and basis are on the 1099-B form so there isn't much "calculation" involved; just one subtraction. Do you mean you want to calculate the capital gains *tax* instead?

Comment: Actually, what I am interested in is how much money that I made. Is "capital gain" equal the total money that I made from trading stocks?

Comment: Based on your comment, it sounds like you are asking about what "capital gain" is. Here are two answers that might help you. And then perhaps you can edit your question to make it more clear what you are asking. https://money.stackexchange.com/a/55710/81641 and https://money.stackexchange.com/a/78870/81641 (The other answers on that second question are also useful.)